# finding web element containing specific text gives different result when we use variable as search text in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am using selenium in python
I am searching for specific text on webpage then I display the text of coresponding web element
This code works alright

```py
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://tophunt.in/amazon-quiz-14-march-2021/'
driver.get(url)
sourcecode = driver.page_source
if 'Answer 1' in sourcecode:
    print('Answer 1 text found in source code of webpage')
    answeroneele = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Answer 1')]")
    print(len(answeroneele), 'having Answer 1')
    input('wait')
    for elements in answeroneele:
        full_answer = elements.get_attribute('textContent')
        print(full_answer)
driver.quit()
```

But if I use variable in searching web element then I get 553 elements that match . Looks like whole web page got printed. The code is

```py
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://tophunt.in/amazon-quiz-14-march-2021/'
driver.get(url)
sourcecode = driver.page_source
str_to_search = 'Answer 1'
if 'Answer 1' in sourcecode:
    print('Answer 1 text found in source code of webpage')
    answeroneele = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), str_to_search)]")
    print(len(answeroneele), 'having Answer 1')
    input('wait')
    for elements in answeroneele:
        full_answer = elements.get_attribute('textContent')
        print(full_answer)
driver.quit()
```

Why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: Answer is - Use f-string format as shown below OR make xpath search string separately like - xpath_for_search='//*[contains(text(),'+"'"+str_to_search+"')]" followed by answeroneele=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_for_search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) function determines whether the first argument string contains the second argument string and returns boolean true or false. It operates on strings, but if object of any other type is passed then it is converted to string using the [`string`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#section-String-Functions) function.

- `text()` is a selector that matches all text nodes that are children of the context node and it returns a node set.
- If a node set is passed to the string function it returns the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#dt-string-value) of the node in the node-set that is first in [document order](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#dt-document-order). If the node set is empty then an empty string is returned.

In `contains(text(), str_to_search)` when the `string` function is applied on `str_to_search` it returns an empty string hence it matches every children of the context node that contains any text.

To solve this issue you can use string interpolation

- For python versions >= 3.6 you can use `f-strings`

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{str_to_search}')]")
```

- For older python versions you can use `str.format`

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{}')]".format(str_to_search))
```

Comment: It seems that string value is expanded inside xpath argument but now I get - SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[contain
s(text(), Answer 1)]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)

Comment: This worked -  answeroneele=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{str_to_search}')]") Note that search string is enclosed in single quotes . Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. {str_to_search} should be enclosed in single quotes, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Happy to help :), can you also upvote my answer if it helped you?

Comment: Done . Nice explanation . Initially I had just ticked right .

Answer (score -1):

You wrote `str_to_search` inside double-quotes, so to python it's just part of a string literal. What you want is for python to replace the value of that variable (doing so-called *string interpolation*), you can use the f-string syntax for this:

```
answeroneele=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//*[contains(text(), '{str_to_search}')]")
```

Note the `f` before the opening quote and the `{}` around the variable name.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why this happens.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use string interpolation in python `{variable}`

```
answeroneele=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '{str_to_search}')]")
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why this happens.